How to resolve missing entities in EDMX after updating the database schema?
I'm working on an ASP.NET application using Entity Framework with an .EDMX file. Recently, I updated my database schema by adding a new table and modifying some existing ones. However, when I tried to refresh the model in Visual Studio, some entities did not appear in the EDMX diagram.
Steps I've tried:

Right-clicked on the .EDMX designer and selected "Update Model from Database."
Verified that the new table is checked in the "Add" tab during the update process.
Checked the .edmx file in XML view to see if there are any errors.

I received an error message

The type 'MyNewEntity' cannot be mapped to the database table 'dbo.MyNewTable' because it does not exist

What steps should I take to ensure all entities are correctly represented in the .EDMX? Is there a way to manually add missing entities if the automatic refresh doesn't work?

Sometimes you just have to try again after restarting Visual Studio. I can't remember I ever had this error. Does the table contain unsupported datatypes?
